# How to differentiate between USB host and USB charger through software

Tags: linux, usb

I am using IMX8MM platform as slave USB device. I want to differentiate between USB host and USB charger when USB cable is connected using linux OS. I tried "udevadm monitor" which gives event on USB detection with host and charger. Please provide me a lead.

Thanks,
Ajita